# Is my implementation of a neural network correct? Model from scratch does not converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

I am trying to implement a neural network with 2 layers from scratch. Despite the code being able to generate the gradients, I am afraid they do not seem correct. Gradient checking also outputs a much higher value to the gradients and therefore checking fails.

I am using MSE for the cost function. Here is the code for my network, please feel free to ignore the implementation of gradient checking as it is not the main subject of my question:

```
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork:
  def __init__(self, X, y):
    self.weights1 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (50, X.shape[1] + 1))
    self.weights2 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1, self.weights1.shape[0] + 1))
    self.m = X.shape[0]
    self.X = np.hstack((np.ones((self.m, 1)), X))
    self.y = y

  def forward(self, weights = None):
      if weights is None:
        o1 = self.weights1 @ self.X.T
        a1 = np.vstack((np.ones((1, o1.shape[1])), self.relu(o1)))
        o2 = self.weights2 @ a1
        return o2
      else:
        o1 = weights[0] @ self.X.T
        a1 = np.vstack((np.ones((1, o1.shape[1])), self.relu(o1)))
        o2 = weights[1] @ a1
        return o2

  def relu(self, x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

  def gradient_checking(self, weights, grads):
    epsilon = 1e-7

    i_idx = np.random.randint(0, weights.shape[0], size=5)
    j_idx = np.random.randint(0, weights.shape[1], size=5)

    for i, j in zip(i_idx, j_idx):
      mask = np.zeros_like(weights)
      mask[i][j] = 1
      epsilon_mask = epsilon*mask
      try:
        weights1_pos, weights2_pos = self.weights1, self.weights2+epsilon_mask
        weights1_neg, weights2_neg = self.weights1, self.weights2-epsilon_mask
      except:
        weights1_pos, weights2_pos = self.weights1+epsilon_mask, self.weights2
        weights1_neg, weights2_neg = self.weights1-epsilon_mask, self.weights2

      preds1 = self.forward((weights1_pos, weights2_pos))
      error1 = self.cost(preds1)
      preds2 = self.forward((weights1_neg, weights2_neg))
      error2 = self.cost(preds2)
      c_grad = (error1 - error2) / (2 * epsilon)
      # print(grads[i][j], c_grad)

  def calc_grads(self, preds, i):
    delta2 = (preds - self.y) / self.m
    a1 = np.vstack((np.ones((1, self.m)), self.relu(self.weights1 @ self.X.T)))
    delta1 = (self.weights2[:, 1:].T @ delta2) * self.relu(self.weights1 @ self.X.T)

    grads2 = delta2 @ a1.T * 0.0001
    grads1 = delta1 @ self.X + 0.0001

    return grads1, grads2


  def cost(self, preds):
    return np.sum((preds - self.y).T @ (preds - self.y)) / (2. * self.m)

  def train(self, epochs):
    for i in range(epochs):
      preds = self.forward()
      grads1, grads2 = self.calc_grads(preds, i)
      self.gradient_checking(self.weights2, grads2)
      # print(grads1.shape, grads2.shape)
      error = self.cost(preds)
      self.weights1 = self.weights1 - 0.03 * grads1
      self.weights2 = self.weights2 - 0.03 * grads2
      # print(grads1.mean(), grads2.mean())
      # print(error)
```

I am then training it as follows:

```
# Generate the input data
X = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
X[:, 2] = X[:, 0]**2

# Generate the target data
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * X[:, 0])

model = NeuralNetwork(X, y)

model.train(200)
```

The results I get are rather strange and I really don't have much of an idea where to go now.

```
preds = model.forward()

error = np.mean((preds - y)**2)
print("Error:", error)

-> Error: 0.4923231441277094
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], preds)
[plotting preds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoqZ8.png)
```

Edit:
Changed the ReLu activation from:
`(x > 0).astype(float)`
to:
`np.maximum(0, x)`

Comment: Why did you forward propagate when the weights are null? Why do you pass the `weights` parameter and `None` value as its default value?